# Web Scraping and Downloading

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am wondering if it is possible to scrape data from a given URL in python. What I am trying to achieve is to download each article posted on the WHO website that is centered around the COVID-19. The articles start on Jan. 15th and a new one is posted every day. I am trying to find an excel format of the daily CoViD-19 case report and download it. I know that each article is able to be downloaded on a pdf but I was trying to figure out a way to do that through python. Please let me know if you have any suggestions or advice or if this is even possible. I tried to attach the view of that page source for each article but it has them listed individually.

https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/situation-reports

from this URL page view

view-source:https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/situation-reports

the section copied as of today (04/20/2020)

````
    <div>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200416-sitrep-87-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=9523115a_2">Situation report - 87</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />16 April 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200415-sitrep-86-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=c615ea20_6">Situation report - 86</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />15 April 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200414-sitrep-85-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=7b8629bb_4">Situation report - 85</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />14 April 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200413-sitrep-84-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=44f511ab_2"><strong>Situation report - 84</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />13 April 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200412-sitrep-83-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=697ce98d_4">Situation report - 83</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />12 April 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200411-sitrep-82-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=74a5d15_2"><strong>Situation report - 82</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />11 April 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200410-sitrep-81-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=ca96eb84_2"><strong>Situation report - 81</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />10 April 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200409-sitrep-80-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=1b685d64_6">Situation report - 80</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />9 April 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200408-sitrep-79-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=4796b143_6">Situation report - 79</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />8 April 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200407-sitrep-78-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=bc43e1b_2">Situation report - 78</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />7 April 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200406-sitrep-77-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=21d1e632_2">Situation report - 77</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />6 April 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200405-sitrep-76-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=6ecf0977_4">Situation report - 76</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />5 April 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200404-sitrep-75-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=99251b2b_4">Situation report - 75</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />4 April 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200403-sitrep-74-covid-19-mp.pdf?sfvrsn=4e043d03_14">Situation report - 74</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />3 April 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200402-sitrep-73-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=5ae25bc7_6">Situation report - 73</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />2 April 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200401-sitrep-72-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=3dd8971b_2"><strong>Situation report - 72</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />1 April 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200331-sitrep-71-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=4360e92b_8">S</a><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200331-sitrep-71-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=4360e92b_8">ituation report - 71</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />31 March 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200330-sitrep-70-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=7e0fe3f8_4">Situation report - 70</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsnbsp;
            <br />30 March 2020<strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200329-sitrep-69-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=8d6620fa_8"></a></strong></p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200329-sitrep-69-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=8d6620fa_8">Situation report - 69</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />29 March 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200328-sitrep-68-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=384bc74c_8">Situation report - 68</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />28 March 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200327-sitrep-67-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=b65f68eb_4">Situation report - 67</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />27 March 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200326-sitrep-66-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=9e5b8b48_2">Situation report - 66</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />26 March 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200325-sitrep-65-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=ce13061b_2">Situation report - 65</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />25 March 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200324-sitrep-64-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=723b221e_2">Situation report - 64</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />24 March 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200323-sitrep-63-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=b617302d_4"></a><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200323-sitrep-63-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=b617302d_4">Situation report - 63</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />23 March 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200322-sitrep-62-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=755c76cd_2">Situation report - 62</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />22 March 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200321-sitrep-61-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=ce5ca11c_2">Situation report - 61</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />21 March 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200320-sitrep-60-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=d2bb4f1f_2">Situation report - 60</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />20 March 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200319-sitrep-59-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=c3dcdef9_2"><strong>Situation report - 59</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />19 March 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200318-sitrep-58-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=20876712_2"><strong>Situation report - 58</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />18 March 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200317-sitrep-57-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=a26922f2_4"><strong>Situation report - 57</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />17 March 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200316-sitrep-56-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=9fda7db2_6"><strong>Situation report - 56</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />16 March 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200315-sitrep-55-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=33daa5cb_8">Situation report - 55</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />15 March 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200314-sitrep-54-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=dcd46351_8">Situation report - 54</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />14 March 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200313-sitrep-53-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=adb3f72_2"><strong>Situation report - 53</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />13 March 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200312-sitrep-52-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=e2bfc9c0_4">Situation report - 52</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />12 March 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200311-sitrep-51-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=1ba62e57_10">Situation report - 51</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />11 March 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200310-sitrep-50-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=55e904fb_2"><strong>Situation report - 50</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />10 March 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200309-sitrep-49-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=70dabe61_4">Situation report - 49</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />09 March 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200308-sitrep-48-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=16f7ccef_4"><strong>Situation report - 48</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />08 March 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200307-sitrep-47-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=27c364a4_4"><strong>Situation report - 47</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />07 March 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200306-sitrep-46-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=96b04adf_4"><strong>Situation report - 46</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />06 March 2020</p>
        <p><a href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200305-sitrep-45-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=ed2ba78b_4"><strong>Situation report - 45</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />05 March 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200304-sitrep-44-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=93937f92_6">Situation report - 44</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />04 March 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200303-sitrep-43-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=76e425ed_2">Situation report - 43</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />03 March 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200302-sitrep-42-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=224c1add_2">Situation report - 42</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />02 March 2020</p>
        <p><a href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200301-sitrep-41-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=6768306d_2"><strong>Situation report - 41</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />01 March 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200229-sitrep-40-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=849d0665_2">Situation report - 40</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />29 February 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200228-sitrep-39-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=5bbf3e7d_4">Situation report - 39</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />28 February 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200227-sitrep-38-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=2db7a09b_4">Situation report - 38</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />27 February 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200226-sitrep-37-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=2146841e_2">Situation report - 37</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />26 February 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200225-sitrep-36-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=2791b4e0_2"><strong>Situation report - 36</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />25 February 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200224-sitrep-35-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=1ac4218d_2"><strong>Situation report - 35</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />24 February 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200223-sitrep-34-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=44ff8fd3_2"><strong>Situation report - 34</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />23 February 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200222-sitrep-33-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=c9585c8f_4"><strong>Situation report - 33</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />22 February 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200221-sitrep-32-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=4802d089_2">Situation report - 32</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />21 February 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200220-sitrep-31-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=dfd11d24_2"><strong>Situation report - 31</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />20 February 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200219-sitrep-30-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=3346b04f_2">Situation report - 30</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />19 February 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200218-sitrep-29-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=6262de9e_2"><strong>Situation report - 29</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />18 February 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200217-sitrep-28-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=a19cf2ad_2"><strong>Situation report - 28</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />17 February 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200216-sitrep-27-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=78c0eb78_4"><strong>Situation report - 27</strong></a>
            <br />Coronavirus disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />16 February 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200215-sitrep-26-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=a4cc6787_2">Situation report - 26</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />15 February 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200214-sitrep-25-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=61dda7d_2">Situation report - 25</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />14 February 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200213-sitrep-24-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=9a7406a4_4">Situation report - 24</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />13 February 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200212-sitrep-23-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=41e9fb78_4">Situation report - 23</a></strong>
            <br />Coronavirus disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br />12 February 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200211-sitrep-22-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=fb6d49b1_2"><strong>Situation report - 22</strong></a>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)&nbsp;
            <br />11 February 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200210-sitrep-21-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=947679ef_2"><strong>Situation report - 21</strong></a>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)&nbsp;
            <br />10 February 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200209-sitrep-20-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=6f80d1b9_4"><strong>Situation report - 20</strong></a>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)&nbsp;
            <br />9 February 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200208-sitrep-19-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=6e091ce6_4"><strong>Situation report - 19</strong></a>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)&nbsp;
            <br />8 February 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200207-sitrep-18-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=fa644293_2"><strong>Situation report - 18</strong></a>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)&nbsp;
            <br />7 February 2020</p>
        <div><strong style="background-color:transparent;text-align:inherit;text-transform:inherit;white-space:inherit;word-spacing:normal;caret-color:auto;"><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200206-sitrep-17-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=17f0dca_4">Situation report - 17</a></strong>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)&nbsp;
            <br />6 February 2020</div>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200205-sitrep-16-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=23af287f_4">Situation report - 16&nbsp;- Erratum</a></strong>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)&nbsp;
            <br />5 February 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200204-sitrep-15-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=88fe8ad6_4"><strong>Situation report - 15</strong></a>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)&nbsp;
            <br />4 February 2020<a href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200203-sitrep-14-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=f7347413_4"><strong></strong></a></p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200203-sitrep-14-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=f7347413_4"><strong>Situation report - 14 - Erratum</strong><strong>&nbsp;</strong></a><strong></strong>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)&nbsp;
            <br />3 February 2020<strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200202-sitrep-13-ncov-v3.pdf?sfvrsn=195f4010_6"></a></strong></p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200202-sitrep-13-ncov-v3.pdf?sfvrsn=195f4010_6">Situation report - 13</a></strong>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)&nbsp;
            <br />2 February 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200201-sitrep-12-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=273c5d35_2"><strong>Situation report - 12</strong></a>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)&nbsp;
            <br />1 February 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200131-sitrep-11-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=de7c0f7_4"><strong>Situation report - 11</strong></a>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)&nbsp;
            <br />31 January 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200130-sitrep-10-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=d0b2e480_2"><strong>Situation report - 10</strong></a>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)&nbsp;
            <br />30 January 2020</p>
        <p><strong><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200129-sitrep-9-ncov-v2.pdf?sfvrsn=e2c8915_2">Situation report - 9</a></strong>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)&nbsp;
            <br />29 January 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200128-sitrep-8-ncov-cleared.pdf?sfvrsn=8b671ce5_2"><strong>Situation report - 8</strong></a>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)&nbsp;
            <br />28 January 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200127-sitrep-7-2019--ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=98ef79f5_2"><strong>Situation report - 7</strong></a>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)&nbsp;
            <br />27 January 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200126-sitrep-6-2019--ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=beaeee0c_4"><strong>Situation report - 6</strong></a>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)&nbsp;
            <br />26 January 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200125-sitrep-5-2019-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=429b143d_8"><strong>Situation report - 5</strong></a>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)&nbsp;
            <br />25 January 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200124-sitrep-4-2019-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=9272d086_8"><strong>Situation report - 4</strong></a>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)&nbsp;
            <br />24 January 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200123-sitrep-3-2019-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=d6d23643_8"><strong>Situation report - 3</strong></a>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)
            <br />23 January 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200122-sitrep-2-2019-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=4d5bcbca_2"><strong>Situation report - 2</strong></a>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)
            <br />22 January 2020</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200121-sitrep-1-2019-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=20a99c10_4"><strong>Situation report - 1</strong></a>
            <br />Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)
            <br />21 January 2020</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>

</div>```
````

Comment: Have a look to [Simple Scraper](https://simplescraper.io/)

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible and not even that hard. I recommend the [Beautifulsoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library which is excellent at parsing HTML pages like that.

Now, you don't need Python at all to solve your task, just use the ubiquitous `wget` command

```
wget --accept '*.pdf' --recursive --level=1 https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/situation-reports
```

Comment: How would you suggest going about to use BeautifulSoup4?

Comment: How about: find_all on element ”a”, pick out all with extension .pdf, then downloading them